# Gson - how to use JsonWriter?

Tags: java, gson

I'm trying to save big object to JSON. I use Gson, but I've got an exception related to memory (Java heap space). I read that I should use serialization. But I do not know how to do it to the end. I'm trying to create a JsonWriter, but I've got exception that JsonWriter is abstract method and I have to override methods: writeArray(); writeObject(); write() and close(). I don`t know how to override them.

Code:

```
private void sendFile(sessContext sc,OutputStream out){
String shipId = sc.getRequest().getParameter("shipid");
Ship ship = m_ship.find(Long.parseLong(shipId));
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .excludeFieldsWithModifiers(Modifier.STATIC, Modifier.TRANSIENT, Modifier.VOLATILE)
 .setPrettyPrinting()
                .create();

try{
     JsonWriter writer = new JsonWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "UTF-8")); //<- error "'JsonWriter' is abstract, cannot be instantiated"
String toJson = gson.toJson(ship); // <- error ("Java heap space")
sendFile(sc,ship);}
catch(Excepiton e){
 e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you please add the stack trace here. ? And why you try to instantiate JsonWriter. You can directly convert any object to JSON using Gson.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have forgotten to import the Gson JsonWriter class so the compiler thinks you are trying to use the JEE interface with the same name

Add

```
import com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter;
```

and make sure you have no import like `javax.json.*` or `javax.json.JsonWriter`